# Wordpress blog page with $_GET

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

In my wordpress (3.4) blog, I have created a page called "mypage". Using my rewrite settings, it is shown in the address bar as *http://www.domain.com/profile*.

I am using a custom page template and am processing some things, which include the use of GET variables. For instance:

```
if (isset($_GET='n')) { echo $_GET['n']; }
```

So, *http://www.mysite.com/profile?n=username* will display "username".
The problem I am having is rewriting the URL so that it can look like: *http://www.mysite.com/profile/username*, still being able to access "username" as the GET variable.

Does anyone know what I need to add to my .htaccess to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes.
`RewriteRule ^profil/(.*)$ ?p=45&n=$1 [L,QSA]`
`RewriteRule ^profil/([^/])/?$ profil?n=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Try using `$_POST` to send the variables. `$_GET` always shows the query string in the browser bar, if you remove it the script won't be able to **get** it. This cannot be solved in .htaccess, unless I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your public variables (`query_vars` filter hook) first then catch it with `get_query_var()` via `template_redirect` action hook

And you might want to read [Custom_Queries - Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries)

Comment: Are you able to give some initial help as to how to do this?